# Manejar error con cuenta existente firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth

tengo un login donde inician mediante facebook. Quiero agregar la opción de iniciar sesión mediante Twitter. Pero para eso tambien debo ser capaz de manejar errores con cuentas que tienen el mismo correo que ya hayan sido registradas antes.
Es decir, si un usuario se registra con facebook con el correo 123@correo.com y luego quiere entrar con twitter con el correo 123@correo.com. Debo detectar eso y manejarlo. La documentación da como ejemplo este código:

```js
// Step 1.
// User tries to sign in to Twitter.
auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider()).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
  if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
    // Step 2.
    // User's email already exists.
    // The pending Twitter credential.
    var pendingCred = error.credential;
    // The provider account's email address.
    var email = error.email;
    // Get registered providers for this email.
    auth.fetchProvidersForEmail(email).then(function(providers) {
      // Step 3.
      // If the user has several providers,
      // the first provider in the list will be the "recommended" provider to use.
      if (providers[0] === 'password') {
        // Asks the user his password.
        // In real scenario, you should handle this asynchronously.
        var password = promptUserForPassword(); // TODO: implement promptUserForPassword.
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
          // Step 4a.
          return user.link(pendingCred);
        }).then(function() {
          // Twitter account successfully linked to the existing Firebase user.
          goToApp();
        });
        return;
      }
      // All the other cases are external providers.
      // Construct provider object for that provider.
      // TODO: implement getProviderForProviderId.
      var provider = getProviderForProviderId(providers[0]);
      // At this point, you should let the user know that he already has an account
      // but with a different provider, and let him validate the fact he wants to
      // sign in with this provider.
      // Sign in to provider. Note: browsers usually block popup triggered asynchronously,
      // so in real scenario you should ask the user to click on a "continue" button
      // that will trigger the signInWithPopup.
      auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        // Remember that the user may have signed in with an account that has a different email
        // address than the first one. This can happen as Firebase doesn't control the provider's
        // sign in flow and the user is free to login using whichever account he owns.
        // Step 4b.
        // Link to Twitter credential.
        // As we have access to the pending credential, we can directly call the link method.
        result.user.link(pendingCred).then(function() {
          // Twitter account successfully linked to the existing Firebase user.
          goToApp();
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Mi problema está en esta parte:

```
var provider = getProviderForProviderId(providers[0]);
auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
```

El navegador me dice:

> getProviderForProviderId" is not defined

No se que debo hacer con las 2 lineas anteriores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El pseudocódigo en inglés esta diciendo que tenés que implementar la función `getProviderForProviderId`. Entonces tenés que implementarla. Buscá en la documentacion, cada provider tiene un [`PROVIDER_ID`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider?hl=es-419#.PROVIDER_ID) que es el que tenés que comparar. Algo así como:

```js
function getProviderForId(id) {
  switch(id) {
    case firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID:
      return new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
    case firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID:
      return new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  //case ... Todos los casos por cada Provider que uses en tu proyecto
  }
  
}
```

Sin embargo, si leés [la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?hl=es-419#fetchProvidersForEmail), te darás cuenta de que el método `fetchProvidersForEmail` está obsoleto. Ahora debés usar [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html?hl=es-419#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail).

Si cambias el código para usar el nuevo método entonces tendrás que comparar, ya no el `PROVIDER_ID`, sino los `...SIGN_IN_METHOD` de cada provider. En el caso de autenticación por email, existen [dos métodos](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider?hl=es-419#.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD).